# EBCDIC support in c#

Tags: c#, ebcdic

If I have an bytes array for EBCDIC encoding, how can I convert it to a c# string?

I tried:

```
string str= Encoding.GetEncoding("EBCDIC").GetString(bytes);

string str= Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-EBCDIC").GetString(bytes);
```

but got exception:

```
'EBCDIC' is not a supported encoding name

'UTF-EBCDIC' is not a supported encoding name
```

Is it a legacy encoding not supported in .Net anymore?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Convert COMP-3 Packed Decimal to Human-Readable Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142972/c-convert-comp-3-packed-decimal-to-human-readable-value)

Comment: TL;DR: `Encoding.GetEncoding(37)` for EBCDIC.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks very much. Although not 100%, it gives me a hint. I need to call {Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);} first before getting the encoding. After calling, I can get the encoding by {Encoding.GetEncoding(37)} as you said or by {Encoding.GetEncoding("ibm037");}. I guess it depend on the running environment. For some environments where ibm037 exists by default, there is no need to call RegisterProvider.

Comment: Ebcdic is a family of encodings, IBM037/cp037 is US-EBCDIC, ibm273/cp273 is german etc.